# Change a variable value on ajax success according to server response vai php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>organisation Name</th>
          <th>User name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Contact No</th>
          <th>IP</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr class="success"> <td>3</td>
        <td>Harshit </td>
        <td>AtulSaini</td>
        <td>arpitkumar@gmail.com</td>
        <td>786048</td>
        <td>::1</td>
        <td>14/03/2015</td><td><button id="status"><span class="label label-success">Active</span></button></td></tr><tr class="none"> <td>4</td>
        <td>Meghaa.co.edu</td>
        <td>megha</td>
        <td>meghaa16@gmail.com</td>
        <td>786048</td>
        <td>::1</td>
        <td>14/03/2015</td><td><button id="status"><span class="label label-success">Active</span></button></td></tr>            

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Hello to all I want last if condition to execute on the server response which alters the res variable 
The problem is when i put the whole if block of code in ajax success then variable "this" value get changed which disables the code to change the tr 
and if i keep it outside as i have done here then the variable res gets destroyed as it is in a success function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".label").click(function() {
    var idx = $(this).parents("tr").find('td:first').html();
    var status = $(this).parents("tr").find('span').html();
    var cname=$(this).parents('tr').attr("class");
    alert(this);

    $.ajax({
        url : "scripts/update.php",
        type : 'GET',
        data : {
            "status" : status,
            "id" : idx
        },
        error : function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        },
        success : function(entry) {
            var res = entry;    

        }
    });
  alert(status);
    if (status == 'Active') {
                $(this).parents("tr").removeClass(cname);
                $(this).parents("tr").addClass("warning");
                $(this).removeClass("label-success");
                $(this).addClass("label-warning");
                $(this).text("Deactive");
                alert("Account Deacivated");
            } else {
                $(this).parents('tr').removeClass(cname);
                $(this).parents('tr').addClass("success");
                $(this).removeClass("label-warning");
                 $(this).addClass("label-success");
                $(this).text("Active");
                alert("Account Acivated");

         }
   });
   });   
   </script>
```

Thanx in advance for your help...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve (e.g. what kind of data is stored in `res` / `entry`). But maybe the following will help you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".label").click(function() {
     // store reference for later use (and to avoid creating the same object multiple times)
    var item   = $(this);

    // use the previously stored jQuery item instead of recreating it every time with $(...)
    var idx    = item.parents("tr").find('td:first').html();
    var status = item.parents("tr").find('span').html();

    // ...

    $.ajax({
      url: "scripts/update.php",
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        "status": status,
        "id": idx
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
      },
      success: function(entry) {
        // `item` will still reference to the label you clicked on
      }
    });

  });
});   
</script>
```

Comment: entry gets the response text from server and res gets that data form entry
..........enrty=server response; and res = entry;

Comment: Yeah, but you're not using it anywhere in your example code. I suppose that you're trying to update the value of `status`!?

Comment: Sorry **Jack** it did not work please look at this and item value they are not similar

Comment: You could help solving this issue by providing an example answer from the server and by telling us what you'd actually like to achieve. What is your ajax request supposed to do? BTW: I just saw that your using the same id (`<button id="status">`) twice. Those are meant to be unique.

Comment: okk wait i i will post the php code also AND ** If i use `<button id="status">`  as reference for the tr then code will work only on first tr because id are unique    here is php code to make it more understandable `<?php
if(isset($_GET))
{
 $id=$_GET['id'];
 $status=$_GET['status'];
 if($status=='Active')
  {
   $r='n';
   echo "Deactive";
  }
 else{$r='y';echo"Active";}
 include_once"../../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
 $sql=mysql_query("update orgdetail set org_acc_activated='$r' where org_no='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
} 
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
...
var $this = $(this);
$.ajax({
        url : "scripts/update.php",
        type : 'GET',
        data : {
            "status" : status,
            "id" : idx
        },
        error : function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        },
        success : function(entry) {
            changeStatuts(entry, $this);

        }
    });

    var changeStatuts = function(status, ele){

           if (status == 'Active') {
                ele.parents("tr").removeClass(cname);
                ele.parents("tr").addClass("warning");
                ele.removeClass("label-success");
                ele.addClass("label-warning");
                ele.text("Deactive");
                alert("Account Deacivated");
            } else {
                ele.parents('tr').removeClass(cname);
                ele.parents('tr').addClass("success");
                ele.removeClass("label-warning");
                ele.addClass("label-success");
                ele.text("Active");
                alert("Account Acivated");

         }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after reading your comment, maybe something like the following could solve your problem. BUT: Your PHP code seems to be vulnerable against a [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".label").click(function() {
    // store reference for later use (and to avoid creating the same object multiple times)
    var item   = $(this);

    // use the previously stored jQuery item instead of recreating it every time with $(...)
    var parentRow = item.parents("tr");
    var idx       = parentRow.find('td:first').html();
    var status    = parentRow.find('span').html();

    $.ajax({
      url: "scripts/update.php",
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        "status": status,
        "id": idx
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
      },
      success: function(status) {
        if (status == 'Active') {
          parentRow.removeClass(cname);
          parentRow.addClass("warning");
          item.removeClass("label-success").addClass("label-warning").text("Deactive");
          alert("Account Deacivated");
        } else {
          parentRow.removeClass(cname);
          parentRow.addClass("success");
          item.removeClass("label-warning").addClass("label-success").text("Active");
          alert("Account Acivated");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});   
</script>
```